# Running a program to output in Dutch

Tags: bash, shell, sudo, environment-variables, locale

I'm running KDE Arch linux and trying to update my system using pacman and have it output in Dutch.

I've tried the following

```
sudo LANG=nl_NL.UTF-8 pacman -Syy
sudo KDE_LANG=nl_NL.UTF-8 pacman -Syy
```

But neither of them worked.

I've also tried editing my `/etc/locale.gen` file and running `locale-gen` but that didn't work either.

I know pacman supports localization, but I can't seem to get it to output in any of the major languages.

Comment: Just to make sure, is your `LANG` set correctly in `/etc/locale.conf`? And you'd try to run this: `LANG=nl_NL.UTF-8 sudo pacman -Syy`.

Comment: `LANG` is set to `en_US.UTF-8`, so I don't think there's any troubles there. I'm not trying to set anything else to Dutch just trying to get pacman to output in it.

Comment: Ah, now I see what you meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The locale variable to control the language of a program is `LC_MESSAGES`. The variable `LANG` is a fallback when more specific `LC_xxx` settings are not present. So if you already have `LC_MESSAGES=en_US` set (for example), changing `LANG` won't have the desired effect. In any case, if you want Dutch messages but not otherwise Dutch settings, `LC_MESSAGES` is what you need to set.

```
sudo LC_CTYPE=nl_NL.UTF-8 pacman -Syy
```

Note that `LC_ALL` trumps all; you should never set it except as `LC_ALL=C` in programs where you want to ignore ambient locale settings. Also, `LANGUAGE` is a GNU libc feature which can override even `LC_ALL`, so make sure to unset it.

Comment: That works, thank you. I had no idea how complicated this was going to become...

Answer (score -1):

I think `sudo` doesn't export your variables, check this:

```
# sudo FOO=bar echo ${FOO}

#
```

Maybe should create a script with `LANG=nl_NL.UTF-8 pacman $*` and call this script with `sudo`.

Comment: No, that also doesn't work unfortunately. When using a command with sudo, you pass it before the command, so it doesn't set the variable for sudo `sudo [-AbEHnPS] [-C fd] [-g group name|#gid] [-p prompt] [-r role]
   [-t type] [-u user name|#uid] [VAR=value] [-i | -s] [command]`

Comment: Hm, indeed. But why doesn't work my example?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure. I've tried it multiple ways, even using `LC_ALL` but none of them work. I before figured I was running the command wrong, but after alot of discussion on this topic at SO I arrived the decision there might be something wrong with the localization portion of my system.

Comment: No, `sudo FOO=bar somecommand` does set `FOO` when running `somecommand`. But in your code snippet, the command that you pass to `sudo` is `echo` with no argument, because `${FOO}` is expanded by the shell that you run `sudo` from. Try `sudo FOO=bar sh -c 'echo $FOO'` (pay attention to the quoting) or `sudo FOO=bar env`.